# Parking On Side of Car Slanting

Tags: car, parking

Will it affect your car if you park one side slanting? 
Something like this in the picture?

**NOTE: The right side is parking higher than this in the picture.**

Thanks

[image: Car Slant]

Comment: Cars tilt side to side all the time, why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: @SolarMike. I mean the weight goes to the left side cause I’m parking slanting. Will it cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state the angle the car is subjected to.  However, in everyday life most cars in the US are parked with the right side low if parallel parked on a graded street.  In hilly areas, many driveways used for parking are not level.

So is the effect on the car significant?  Generally no.  Is it measurable, yes.  What gets affected?

-suspension
-tires, there can be significant side loads 
-battery, uneven electrolyte coverage of plates
-fuel, low tank level might have spotty pickup 
-water drainage, placing higher leakage loads on some sealing components

Most of these effects are unlikely to affect vehicles in more normal situations.  However if your parking angle is something more severe, like 30 degrees or more, there could be some adverse issues. Generally, these are not a factor for the vast majority us users.

Notable exceptions include cross-fed saddle tanks, where uneven lateral leveling could cause cross-feed which would overfill the lower tank, where both tanks were nearly full. This has caused some diesel fuel spills in trucks. I know of no passenger cars affected by this fuel tank configuration.

So bottom line, cars are robust with respect to levelness of parking, but there are some risks, and there are measurable effects, but they are usually of little consequence.

Answer (score 2):

In the real world - **No** this isn't going to make a difference to anything. You'd have to be getting to some pretty extreme angles (i.e. the car is literally about to tip on to it's side).

Yes you're slightly shifting the weight of the car on to one side but the involved components (suspension, wheels, tires, etc) are built to take far greater loads than this is going to ask them to handle. Honestly if a car was going to be negatively affected by parking at an angle like this parking would be the least of your problems - it likely wouldn't be capable of coping with the general day-to-day demands of driving.